# How to preview a RDL in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've looked everywhere and I cant seem to find a way to preview the report.  Does anybody have any ideas?  I have looked everywhere for preview and under report I havent seen preview.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "preview". What kind of project is this .rdl file in?

Comment: it's an RDLC and it's in a reports project

Comment: in VS2005 you had the ability to preview the report in VS without loading it to the report server